# Why does the caret move when I try to limit the length of bootstrap button text?

Tags: css

Look at these two buttons, styled with Bootstrap:

```css
body { margin: 10px !important; }

button.limited-text-length span.text {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" type="button">
  <span class="text">Dropdown</span>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<button class="btn limited-text-length" type="button">
  <span class="text">Dropdown</span>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

In the second one I tried to forcibly limit the length of the label by setting `width`, `display: inline-block` and `overflow-x: hidden`. However, as you can see, this causes the dropdown triangle to move downwards. Why is that and how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You converted your span into `inline-block`.
Adding `vertical-align:middle` will position the inline-block item in the middle of the line.

```css
body { margin: 10px !important; }

button.limited-text-length span.text {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" type="button">
  <span class="text">Dropdown</span>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<button class="btn limited-text-length" type="button">
  <span class="text">Dropdown</span>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```